# How to retrieve ip list from external webpage with php?

Tags: php, ip, tor

I need to send all TOR users to a custom captcha.

How can I retrieve this ip list with php:

[Tor Bulk Exit List](https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=8.8.8.8)

This is my php code:

```
  // Retrieve ip list
  $deny_ips = file('https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=8.8.8.8');

  // Read user ip address
  $ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) : '';

  // Search current IP in $deny_ips array and present Captcha
  if ( (array_search($ip, $deny_ips))!== FALSE ) {
    echo 'Captcha goes here!';
    exit;
  }
```

The first step "Retrieve ip list" is not correct and I do not know how to retrieve it with php.

Thank you!

Comment: In which way is it not correct? Perhaps http(s) fopen wrappers are disabled in your config?

Comment: I suspect it is because in the first step it is not a file but rather a webpage. I tried all sorts of things like 'array' for example. Unfortunately, my understanding of php is still limited.

Comment: `file()` can read URLs, as long as the fopen wrappers are enabled. See the info in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: You did not mention the error / misbehaviour in your question.

Comment: Thanks ccKep for your time. Didn't knew file() can read post's contents. Well, it is not working because while using tor I can see the website. How can I know why is not working? How can I see if fopen is enabled? I never heard about fopen so I'm familiar with it. I'm a newbie at php. I will try without url protocol...

Comment: just try `var_dump($deny_ips);` after `$deny_ips = file(....);` and see if it prints out the files contents in array form. If it does, add a `var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);` and see if your address actually matches any of the entries (by hand)

Comment: It took me some time to realise it is working, I had a typo in my original code. Shame on me. Thanks for pushing it further with your comments and for the tips. All 3 methods in this post works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an idea.

```
$tor = file_get_contents('https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=8.8.8.8');
$array = explode('#', $tor);
$ips = end($array);
$ips_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $ips);

If( in_array($ip, $ip_array) ){
    echo 'ip found <br>';
}else{
    echo 'ip not found <br>';
}
```

That might do it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I will try you solution and report the results later.

Comment: Your solution works along with my original post and the other solution posted by me. I accepted your answer because you were very fast with your support and your answer it's different from all other solutions I found online. I also do understand more or less your code, whereas the other solution I posted it's more tor specific and I do not understand the code that much. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to check it here: [Check if user uses TOR](http://www.codegist.net/snippet/php/tor_functionsphp_j3j5_php)

So the code is this one:

```
/**
 * detect if current user is using tor network
 * @return bool
 */
function IsTorExitPoint(){
  if (gethostbyname(ReverseIPOctets($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).".".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].".".ReverseIPOctets($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']).".ip-port.exitlist.torproject.org")=="127.0.0.2") {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  } 
}

/**
 * reverse the ip
 * @param string $input
 * @return string
 */
function ReverseIPOctets($inputip){
  $ipoc = explode(".",$inputip);
  return $ipoc[3].".".$ipoc[2].".".$ipoc[1].".".$ipoc[0];
}

/**
 * present custom captcha to user using tor network
 */
if (IsTorExitPoint()) {
  echo 'Captcha goes here!';
  exit;
}
```

Not sure what's the best way to do it according to performance issues. Is there any way to check it with php?

I will report back more info after try all the possible solutions.

Thanks.